# How to SUM values from two columns

Tags: sql, select, count, sum

I have the following information in a table

```
    Load Number  Origin  Destination
    1            AR      TX
    2            AR      AL
    3            TX      MS
    4            WA      AR
```

I need help with a SQL statement that will produce the follow results

```
    State      Origin   Destination
    AR         2        1
    TX         1        1
    WA         1        
    MS                  1
```

I have tried countless types of SELECT statements with various types of COUNTS in them and GROUP BY's at the end but I can't get the results I'm looking for.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
select state,
       sum(origin) origin,
       sum(destination) destination
from   (select origin as state,
               0 as destination,
               1 as origin
        from   my_table
        union all
        select destination,
               1,
               0
        from   my_table)
group by state
```

Comment: I definitely think this is the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can first build a inner query to select all the distinct states from Origin and Destination columns. Then you can join it back to the main table and do a conditional aggregation.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/246885/2)

```
select x.state, 
sum(case when x.state = t.Origin then 1 end),
sum(case when x.state = t.Destination then 1 end)
from tablename t 
join (
select Origin as State
from tablename
union
select Destination
from tablename ) x
on t.Origin = x.state or t.Destination = x.state
group by x.state
```